# Testers cannot publish test results in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-2010

We started to use MTM 2010 for creating and publishing test cases in TFS 2010. Unfortunately, users are not able to publish test results due to lack of permissions.

I do not want to grant code access to testers. Currently, they have only “View project-level information” permissions. Could you please advise what (minimal) permissions should I grant to testers so they can run test from MTM and publish the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grant following project level permissions to testers, beside permissions they already have:

“Create test runs”

“Manage test configurations”

“Manage test environments”

“View test runs”

Also, be sure that in Area security for specific projects, testers do have “Manage test plans” permissions, beside permissions you have already assigned to them. If you want to be sure that testers do not have access to code, you can always set Deny permissions for specific files in project.